# Find duplicates by column in a file

Tags: text-processing, uniq

I have an input file containing file paths and their md5sum, separated by semicolons and sorted by md5 hashes :

```
/media/LaCie/Images/recup2/recup_dir.1/f1295328.jpg;0080ececd3da8533f5d11e449cf73287
/media/LaCie/Documents/pics/897_FUJI/DSCF7042.JPG;0081cd15705f0c541995e13ad3e405b8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Images/Trashes/501/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
/media/LaCie/Images/2009-09/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
```

I'd like to know how I could find duplicates based on the hash, and print them, so the output for the above input would look like this :

```
/media/LaCie/Images/Trashes/501/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
/media/LaCie/Images/2009-09/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
```

I tried `uniq`, but I couldn't find how to change its field separator from  spaces to semicolons (some file paths may have spaces in them)

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If your paths don't contain spaces or semicolons, just turn the semicolons into spaces.

```
tr ';' ' ' | uniq -f 1 -d | tr ' ' ';'
```

If your paths contain spaces but no tabs or semicolons, you can do basically the same thing — but temporarily turn spaces into semicolons, and use a tab as the field separator.

```
tr '; ' '\t;' | uniq -f 1 -d | tr '\t;' '; '
```

If you don't want to make any assumptions on the file names (other than not containing newlines), you can make awk do the job instead.

```
awk -F ';' '{
    if ($NF == current) {
        if (first != "") print first;
        first = "";
        print;
    } else {
        first = $0;
        current = $NF;
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution could be using following `awk`:

```
awk -F";" 'FNR == NR { x[$2]++; next; } { if ($2 in x && x[$2] > 1) print; }' file file
```

Caveat with this is that file is read twice. In the first pass we count and store repetitions in array and in the second pass we print row if counter is greater then 1.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with `perl` (for bonus points - you could do the `md5sum` bit as well).

But something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %file_md5; 

while ( <> ){
   chomp; 
   my ( $filename, $hash ) = split /;/; 
   if ( $file_md5{$hash} ) { 
       print "$filename has the same md5sum as $file_md5{$hash}\n";
   }
   $file_md5{$hash} = $filename;
}
```

Note `<>` is the magic filehandle. It takes data piped into the script either via `STDIN` or from files on command line `./myscript.pl file_containing_data`

Answer (score 1):

Among the smarter solutions, here's a brute force "one-liner" that `cut`s out the md5sum, runs it through `uniq -c` to get the counts, uses `awk` to prune out the actually-unique values, then passes the remaining md5sums through a `for` loop to `grep` the matching values from the original file. Certainly not as elegant as Gilles' all-awk solution, and also has the downfall of reading the input-file twice.

```
for md5 in $(cut -d\; -f2 inputfile-here | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 { print $2 }')
do 
  grep ";$md5\$" inputfile-here
  echo  ## gratuitous blank line to separate the duplicates
done
```

I added extra duplicates to your sample input file:

```
/media/LaCie/Images/recup2/recup_dir.1/f1295328.jpg;0080ececd3da8533f5d11e449cf73287
/media/LaCie/Documents/pics/897_FUJI/DSCF7042.JPG;0081cd15705f0c541995e13ad3e405b8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729-1.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729-2.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Images/Trashes/501/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
/media/LaCie/Images/2009-09/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
```

to which the above loop produces:

```
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729-1.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8
/media/LaCie/Documents/Pictures/124_FUJI/DSCF4729-2.JPG;00829232ae6b181654ee87ff32d161f8

/media/LaCie/Images/Trashes/501/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
/media/LaCie/Images/2009-09/IMG_0651.JPG;00833c74523d5361641af863f5d92387
```